# Disappearable text on Imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview

I would like my ImageView to display a placeholder message : `the image will display here`, which should disappear as soon as the image is displayed on that ImageView.

Can anyone provide me the solution ?

Comment: Could you provide the code that loads the image  on your ImageView ?

Comment: You can have a drawable that says exactly that and then once the image is loaded from the web service or whatever you're fetching it from simply replace this drawable with the loaded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you what you are using so I am going to cover all the options

> 1) If you are just viewing it locally(without internet)

Just make an image of the same size as the image view and using paint or any other editor write "the image will display here"

OR

Do this

```
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView 

android:text = "the image will display here"
android:id = "@+id/text"/>
<ImageView ..... android:id = "@+id/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

setVisibility of this textView to `VIEW.INVISIBLE` when your image is loading

> 2) If you are loading it from internet

There is a lib named piccasso (google it) you can use that it has all the features

Ask any more questions in comments

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked

Comment: happy to help :),,,Please mark it the correct answer ;P

Answer (score 1):

```
    <RelativeLayout
     ... >


       <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:visibility="gone"
       ...
       />

       <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="the image will display here"
       ...
       />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Usev this for placeholder.. or vice-versa

```
iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout for that. e.g

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content""
            android:src="@drawable/my_image"
            android:contentDescription="@string/MY_IMAGE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageLoaderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/IMAGE_LOADING" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the code you can hide the textview on the successfull image load

e.g.  `mImageLoaderTextView.setVisibility(imageLoaded ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

When the image is loaded, it just appears over the text and hide it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. it helped me

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to do that is to have another view (`TextView` in your case) to be replaced by whatever is loading (`ImageView`) in your case.

I usually use a `ViewSwitcher` to do that.